# Why useEffect hook runs before the DOM is loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have trouble accessing an element from react's useEffect Hook.

```
const Guest = () => {

    useEffect(() => {

        let selectedElement = document.body.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable=true]');
        console.log(selectedElement)

    })

    return (
        <Fragment>
           <div id='guest-editorjs'>
              <Editor
                  tools={{
                     header: Header,
                     list: List,
                     image: Image,
                     delimiter: Delimiter
                  }}
                  holder="guest-editorjs"
                  onChange={(data) => console.log(data)}
                  onReady={() => console.log('Start!')}
                 data={data} />
        </div>
      </Fragment>

}
```

I am trying to access elements that are `contenteditable=true` and all of them are contained inside this Editor component.

But when I run the code, console outputs return `console.log(selectedElement)` (result: empty NodeList) and then `console.log('Start!')` from onReady of Editor component.

But useEffect start work only after render is done or am I wrong at some point?

**Update**: After Guest component renders for the first time the output is: 
- empty NodeList[]
- Start!

**But** when I re-render the component it returns NodeList with all needed elements.

Comment: In functional component useEffect can be used because lifecycle hooks are not available in it. useEffect will always runs before component dom load.[Check this doc and the **TIP**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: `useEffect` without dependencies means `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount`. If you want it to be later, use `useEffect(function, [])`. **[ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)**

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#effect-hook

Comment: @Rajesh, I've tried to pass [] but it's the same result. Is there way in React to wait first while DOM is loaded and only then call the functions?

Comment: Are you sure there are any elements which satisfy the query? 
Because i tried something like this 
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let selectedElement = document.body.querySelectorAll("#guest-editorjs");
    console.log("in effect", selectedElement[0]);
  });

  return <div id="guest-editorjs">hi</div>;
};

And it works perfectly.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, there are. And I agree, query to #guest-editorjs works fine. And also more, query to .codex-editor (it's main parent element from Editor) works also. The problem starts once you try to access next level of children elements. But when Guest component is re-rendered it's makes query to [contenteditable=true] without any troubles. So, I think the problem is in loading of Editor component for the first time.

Comment: You need to check <Editor />, because even with children there should be no  problem to fetch the query elements with useEffect.

Comment: I guess I had the same problem when trying a `scrollIntoView`. it didn't work on the initial page rendering. The effect did run, but elements reported zero size, so the scroll didn't work. On subsequent renderings it did work fine. I added a special effect with `[]` dependency, which runs the `scrollIntoView` as a callback to `window.addEventListener('load',...)` and now it works! It's a bit frustrating that I need two effects to basically do one and the same thing :(

Answer (score 7):

I also faced with this problem and my solution is to create internal state that will be set when the DOM is re-rendered, see the following code to understand:

```js
const [rerender, setRerender] = useState(); // or any state
const [afterRender, setAfterRender] = useState();// internal state

// (1)
useEffect(() => {
   if (!afterRender) return;
   // here DOM is loaded and you can query DOM elements
   // then reset
   setAfterRender(false);
}, [afterRender]);

useEffect(() => {
   setAfterRender(true); // (1) will be called after DOM rendered
}, [rerender]); // or don't set any if you want to listen to all re-render events

return {
  setRerender, // expose function trigger re-render data
}
```

Comment: If return will have object `return {setRerender}` then where will we place our HTML/Components? i.e `return (<Component><i>Hello World</i></Component)`

Comment: @ImranBughio put this code into a react custom hook and reuse it.

Answer (score 6):

***Updated in 2021 (React version 17.0.2)***

useEffect will run after DOM loaded and UI paint (just useLayoutEffect run before UI paint).

It run in order:

1. DOM manipulation.
2. useLayoutEffect
3. UI paint
4. useEffect

It works on both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to the DOM you can use `useLayoutEffect` instead.

`useLayoutEffect` runs after any DOM mutations. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect):

> The signature is identical to `useEffect`, but it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render.

Comment: Facing the same problem as the OP. `useLayoutEffect` doesn't solve it. Didn't I understand correctly that `useLayoutEffect` even runs earlier than `useEffect`, because it's intended to prevent flicker effect?

Comment: @vicmortelmans According to the documentation I linked to `useLayoutEffect` runs in the same phase as `componentDidUpdate`. So rendering should happen before the hook is triggered. It also specifically mentions access to the DOM.

Comment: @vicmortelmans it runs between dom being created and being 'displayed' I think?

Answer (score -2):

As for React version < 17

There is a workaround for this situation by calling the callback from the `onLoad` event

but I think it only works for the first DOM loaded.

```
const App = () => {
    const handleLoaded = () => {
        // action here
    };

    return <div onLoad={handleLoaded}>{/* child here */}</div>;
};
```